# Using jQuery to show previous td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-events

I know this kind of question has been asked 10 billion times.. I've considered them and used what I could.

Basically, I have a text field that I want rendered only when a button is clicked.

This is what my code looks like (it's written in ruby because I'm using ruby on rails).. Also this is in a partial so this code gets displayed over and over on a single page.

```
<td class=search-form-block>
  <%= form_tag({:controller => "foods", :action => "save_selected"}, method: "post") %>
  <%#= text_field_tag 'search_food_text_field', nil, data: { catcomplete_source: search_foods_path } %>

  <%= text_field_tag 'search_food_text_field', nil, data: { catcomplete_source: search_foods_path } %>

</td>
<td class=remove-td-center> <%= link_to "new food", nil,  {class: "new-food-button"} %>     </td>
```

This is what is looks like from source:

```
<td class=search-form-block>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/foods/save_selected" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="nj7UzUO00UwgC0eeZk2GpZiKqz6PPTvLST1mINZCDR4=" /></div>

  <input data-catcomplete-source="/foods/search" id="search_food_text_field" name="search_food_text_field" type="text" />

</td>
<td class=remove-td-center> <a href="/meals/5" class="new-food-button">new food</a> </td>
```

And here is my jQuery that I predicted would work but didn't:

```
 $('.search-form-block').hide()

$('.new-food-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev('td').toggle();
});
```

The problem I'm having is when I hit the toggle button ALL the forms on the page get toggled. I only want the form for that particular button to be rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `this` in your click event. In your function `this` refers to the `link` rather than the `td`. So to get the previous `td` you'd need something like this:

```
$(this).parent().prev('td').toggle();
```

Where you get the parent of the link then the previous td from there.

Comment: Nice! That worked! Now I just have to test and see if the search forms for each work as well. Thanks! I can't accept your answer for another 11 minutes but I will.